# How to build an autocomplete API?

Tags: api, autocomplete

I am trying to wrap my head around building a proper autocomplete functionality. I am practicing by building a really simple API that autocompletes users' names.

Currently, I have a database that contains columns, `given_name` and `last_name`. They are indexed with elasticsearch. And, I have built an API that accepts a search term to query elasticsearch.

I am concerned with how the frontend communicates with this API. The obvious way of doing it is to call the API after every keyup on the search input. However, this is a lot of requests being sent. Making calls after delays to reduce requests feels *hacky*. Is there an appropriate way of doing this?

I have found many guides on how to build an elasticsearch API but nothing that puts frontends and backends together.

Answer (score 7):

For sure, it *is* a lot of calls being issued!  But for most applications, the number of suggestion options precludes client-based autocomplete.

---

However, an effective autocomplete feature should serve to *reduce the number of (much more heavyweight) search requests* being sent/rendered (while improving searcher experience) by reducing misspellings and zero-result searches among others.

Also Elasticsearch typically serves autocomplete requests *fast* (as in <10ms), freeing cluster resources significantly faster than search requests.

---

**Common tweaks to reduce autocomplete-generated server traffic include:**

1. Imposing a minimum entry length (2-3 chars usually) before autocomplete is triggered.
2. Adding a short delay after keyup (0.1-0.3s) before triggering so that fast/confident typists don't generate a burst of unnecessary/intermediate completion requests.
3. Caching recent completion lists in browser so that <backspace> keystrokes don't trigger a server request.
4. Pre-caching suggestions in browser (when feasible/bounded - e.g. Navigation, Friends/Contact names,  etc... )

---

[Twitter Typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) incorporates all of the above API traffic optimizations for in-browser autocomplete.  Take a look!